# AppendChild to JS dynamically created element without redundant code

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to build a simple todo list. I would like to add a (x) to each item in the list. The list has two existing items, and the rest will be added from user input.

My current code can only add (x) to existing items. I followed the following tutorial, but i think the way it adds (x) to both existing items and new input items are redundant. (note it basically uses "var span = document.createElement("SPAN"); ..." twice.

Is there a way that I can append the (x) in the end to all li items in the document?

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var allListItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function appendClose(x){
 var close = document.createElement("span");
 var text = document.createTextNode("(\u00D7)");
 close.appendChild(text);
 return x.appendChild(close);
}
// Turn object into array.
const peopleArray = Object.keys(allListItems).map(i => allListItems[i]);
console.log(peopleArray);
peopleArray.map(appendClose);


// Create new list item after button click. 
function createNewElement(){
 var li = document.createElement("li"); // create <li>
 var v_userInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
 var content = document.createTextNode(v_userInput.value);
 li.appendChild(content);
 document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);

 document.getElementById("myInput").value = ""; //fresh the input box;

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Work to-do</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Work to-do </h1>


<div id="myDiv">
 <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">
 <button id="enter" onclick="createNewElement()">Add</button>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
 <li>Gym</li>
 <li>Food</li>
</ul>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="7_todo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write one more line inside `createNewElement()` to do that:

`appendClose(li);`

Further, you should also prevent empty values being appended to todo-list by checking the length of input value. I've added an example of that.

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var allListItems = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function appendClose(x){
 var close = document.createElement("span");
 var text = document.createTextNode("(\u00D7)");
 close.appendChild(text);
 return x.appendChild(close);
}
// Turn object into array.
const peopleArray = Object.keys(allListItems).map(i => allListItems[i]);
// console.log(peopleArray);
peopleArray.map(appendClose);


// Create new list item after button click. 
function createNewElement(){
 var li = document.createElement("li"); // create <li>
 var v_userInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
  
  // Prevents empty task in todo list
  if(v_userInput.value.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter something!');
    return ;
  }
  
 var content = document.createTextNode(v_userInput.value);
 li.appendChild(content);
        appendClose(li); // Edited here
 document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);

 document.getElementById("myInput").value = ""; //fresh the input box;

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Work to-do</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Work to-do </h1>


<div id="myDiv">
 <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">
 <button id="enter" onclick="createNewElement()">Add</button>
</div>

<ul id="myUL">
 <li>Gym</li>
 <li>Food</li>
</ul>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="7_todo.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: aha yeah! thanks!!

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo this is the redundant example i was talking about (i forgot to paste the link). but you got what i wanted to do. thanks!!